# Open sets which are not closed in the Sorgenfrey line

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

Basically, it is a simple fact about the Sorgenfrey line that:

1. the only connected sets are the singelton sets.
2. the open set in Sorgenfrey line $(b,\infty)$ is not closed.

**But are there other open sets which not closed?**

The argument for 1 and 2 are not difficult. Do you think I am right?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Under any topology the singleton set is connected

Comment: Assuming by singleton you mean $/{x/}$

Comment: Yes, it is but here only set which is connected Singelton mean $\{x\}$

Comment: Hey I haven't thought this through completely yet but have you ever considered the possibility that some if not all singletons are open sets? I'm not completely framilar with the Sorgenfrey so I apologize if this sounds ludicrous.

Comment: I improved your title! Generally the more specific the title, the better.

Comment: Actually, did I get your question right? I am not sure that was exactly what you were asking.

Comment: @6005;was that the actual question? ;i thought OP was asking about the first two facts

Comment: @6005;in that case i don't think my answer would work

Comment: @BobWilson Because of the other answer that existed before yours, I thought that was the question, but now that answer was deleted. I'm not sure what OP originally meant to ask.

Comment: @BobWilson You could just put a note on your answer saying how you interpreted the question.

Comment: good idea ;lets try that @6005

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a subspace of the Sorgenfrey line $S$ and let $a,b\in A$ with $a<b.$ Then $[b,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)=\cup_{x<b}[x,b)$ are open in $S.$ So $A\cap (-\infty,b)$ and $A\cap [b.\infty)$ are relatively open in $A,$ are disjoint, and are not empty, and their union is $ A.$ So $A$ is not connected. So the only connected subspaces of $S$ are the empty set and the $1$-element subsets.

Any open $B\subset S$ such that $(b,c)\subset B$ and $b\not \in B$ is not closed, because any nbhd $U$ of $b$ covers $[b,d)$ for some $d>b,$ so $U\cap B\supset (b,\min (c,d))\ne \emptyset.$ So $b\in \bar B$ \ $B.$ This however is not necessary  in order that $B$ be open but not closed. For example if $B=\cup_{n\in N} [\frac {1}{2n},\frac {1}{2n-1})$ then $0\in \bar B$ \ $B.$ An open $B\subset S$ is not closed iff there exists $b\in S$ \ $B$ such that $b=\inf\; ((b,\infty)\cap B\;).$

Answer (score 1):

To show that the singletons are the only connected sets you need to argue like this:

Let us consider the set $\{a,b\}$ where say $a<b$.

Then the sets $(-\infty ,\dfrac{a+b}{2})\cup [b,\infty 
)$ are both open sets in the sorgenfrey line which form a disconnection of $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Please clarify the question ;Before edit the question was put up as if it wanted how to clarify the claims that you had